# htaccess rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite `/anything.anyextension` into `/?post=anything`.

eg:

- `/this-is-a-post.php` into `/?post=this-is-a-post` or
- `/this-is-a-post.html` into `/?post=this-is-a-post` or even
- `/this-is-a-post/` into `/?post=this-is-a-post`

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/|\.[a-z]{3,4})$ ?$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the main server configuration, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)\.\w+$ /?post=\1 [L]
```

If not, and you are forced to put this in a `.htaccess` file, you could try

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.\w+$ /?post=\1 [L]
```

In either case, this assumes you will only be rewriting URLs with a single path component (i.e. if you get a request like `/path/anything.anyextension` it might not work as you expect, the rewrite rule would need to be modified to handle that)

Comment: This will fail to catch any entry without extensions

Comment: @Ast: yes, that is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need a better way to determine when to apply the rewrite rule, otherwise your page won't be able to display external JS or CSS, unless you define an exception.

[SilverStripe](http://silverstripe.org/) (or the core, Sapphire) offers a good approach to this, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.swf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .+
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+) /?post=$1 [L,R=301]
```

This requires the URI not to be empty, not to be JS, CSS or SWF, and redirects back to your root directory:

```
http://localhost/this-is-a-post.php
http://localhost/?post=this-is-a-post
```

If you don't want a redirection, but the processing, remove the redirection rule `R=301`